# Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/ua.com.android/databases/test.db' to 'ru_UA'

Tags: android, sql

Пишу клиент-сервер приложение, которое все полученные данные сохраняет на локальную базу данных устройства.
При первом подключении к серверу, сохранения данных происходит нормально, без ошибок, я также могу повторно обратиться к серверу, данные допишутся, но проблема в том, что старые данные остаются, а мне нужно заменить или дописать.
Я попробовал изменить версию базы данных в коде и получил ошибку:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid/databases/InternetLessons.db' to 'ru_UA'.
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:393)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
                                                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1148)
                                                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:268)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                                            at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.server.json.ParserCateroriesJson.getCategories(ParserCateroriesJson.kt:37)
                                                                                                            at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.server.addInfoBd.ShowCategories$getWinXak$2.apply(ShowCategories.kt:47)
                                                                                                            at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.server.addInfoBd.ShowCategories$getWinXak$2.apply(ShowCategories.kt:24)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:59)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:58)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:67)
                                                                                                            at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.server.addInfoBd.ShowCategories$getWinXak$1.subscribe(ShowCategories.kt:43)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10838)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
                                                                                                            at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.
```

**В интернете довольно много рекомендаций**, но даже следуя им, я не смог решить проблему.

Базу данных я создавал с помощью программы DB Browser for SQLite. В самой базе я создал 2 таблицы. Выглядит это так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я также пробовал создавать базу данных вручную, через код, такой проблемы после изменения версии не возникало, но тут большой минус для меня, много кода, и мне бы хотелось использовать локальную.

Что вы мне можете посоветовать?

**Что я делаю.**

У меня есть класс который читает базу данных и взаимодействует с ней. В этом классе я и меняю версию БД когда хочу обновить её.

```
public class LocalBD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public String DB_PATH = null;
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    public final Context myContext;

    private SQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper;
//    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    public LocalBDLessonsInternet(Context context, String NameBd) {
        super(context, DB_NAME = NameBd, null, 1); // 1 - версия БД
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";

    }


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }

    public Cursor setQuery(String table,
                           String[] columns,
                           String selection,
                           String[] selectionArgs,
                           String groupBy,
                           String having,
                           String sortOrder) {
        return myDataBase.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder);
    }
```

С сервера мне приходят данные в виде Json, которые на устройстве обрабатываются с помощью библиотеки `com.google.gson.GsonBuilder`.

Далее полученные данные я сразу сохраняю в БД.

```
class ParserCateroriesJson(var context: Context) {

    var mContext : Context = context

    private var cateroriesJson: List<CategoriesJson>? = null

    fun createFromJson(mJson: String): ParserCateroriesJson {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val pj = ParserCateroriesJson(this!!.mContext!!)
        pj.cateroriesJson = Arrays.asList(*gson.fromJson(mJson, Array<CategoriesJson>::class.java))
        return pj


    }

    fun getCategories() {

        val mLocalBD = LocalBD(context, "InternetLessons.db")

        try {
            mLocalBD .createDataBase()
            mLocalBD .openDataBase()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        val db = mLocalBD.getWritableDatabase();

        for (i in 0 until cateroriesJson!!.size) {

            //Добавляем полученную информацию в бау данных

            var values  = ContentValues()
            values.put("_id", cateroriesJson!!.get(i).term_id)
            values.put("nameGroups", cateroriesJson!!.get(i).name)

            db.insert("groups", null, values)

        }

    }

}
```

Все работает хорошо, но когда я закрываю приложение, перехожу в Android Studio, меняю в классе `LocalBD` версию БД, обратно запускаю приложение через Android Studio, и уже при попытки связаться с сервером БД кидает исключение.

Comment: @pavlofff Добрый день, я отредактировал вопрос в котором попытался изложить весь процесс взаимодействия с базой данных.

Comment: а зачем вы при каждом добавлении создаете  базу заново и увеличиваете ей версию?

Comment: @pavlofff , если я не буду вызывать метод `mLocalBD.createDataBase()` при первом запуске приложения, я не смогу создать базу на устройстве  `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database` А меняю версию я для того чтобы данные в БД полностью перезаписать.

Comment: Если я не буду менять версию БД, тогда в БД попадает клон информация.

Comment: Я попробовал после создания базы данных, убрать из кода повторное создание БД, и всё равно меня привело к этой ошибки при обновлении версии в коде.